# Problem in installing & configuring bugzilla

Tags: windows, bugzilla

Can somebody help me in installing bugzilla (list out exact steps if possible) on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.0 , Mysql 5.1 & existing email server(already configured)?
I followed installation steps from many posts & also your site , everything goes right but when I start to creating accounts by sending email in bugzilla web panel, I get error:- “There was an error sending mail from 'bugzilla-daemon@' to 'Jayanti.Katariya@moontechnolabs.com':Can't call method "address" on an undefined value at C:/Program Files (x86)/Bugzilla/perl/perl/site/lib/Email/Send/SMTP.pm line 25.”

I also tried installing through Windows installer, but same issues.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Expecting quick response.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to set a valid email address for your bugzilla-daemon. Please
>   see the data/params file, or visit edit_params.cgi to set the FROM
>   address for bugzilla.

See: http://fixunix.com/mozilla/414644-re-bugzilla-mail-problem.html

Comment: The email i got has incomplete link , i.e. a link without host name & http:// for creating account, how can i set my custom host with http:// for every link sent from bugzillain email ? Please reply fast as i m in the middle of the configuration process.

Comment: Check `urlbase`, `docs_urlbase` and `sslbase`. See: http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/parameters.html